# How can I play object keyframes at the press of a button?

Tags: python, animation, scripting

I want to make a PowerPoint presentation using Blender.

My idea is to have a camera that moves to the next "slide" when you press a button.
At this new slide you can play a short animation by pressing the button again.
And perhaps there's even a constant animation looping in the background.

Is this possible in Blender?

Comment: Yes it is possible with Blender

Answer (score 1):

you can use this script:

```
import bpy

ob = bpy.data.objects['Next']

print("ob is",ob.name)

def object_selected_callback(ob):
    # Do something here
    print("object active ", bpy.context.active_object.name)
    
    if bpy.context.active_object.name == "Next":
        
        cam = bpy.data.objects["Camera"]
        cam.location.x = 21.3
        
    if bpy.context.active_object.name == "Back":
        
        cam = bpy.data.objects["Camera"]
        cam.location.x = 0


def subscribe_to_cube_loc_change(ob):
    
    print("called")
    
    if ob.type != 'MESH':
        return

    subscribe_to = bpy.types.LayerObjects, "active"
    bpy.msgbus.subscribe_rna(
        key = subscribe_to,
        owner = ob,
        args = (ob,),
        notify = object_selected_callback,
        )

subscribe_to_cube_loc_change(ob)
```

which e.g. moves the camera (of course you can extend this so that the cam is animated), if you press on these "buttons" (meshes/cubes), which have to be called "Next" and "Back".

Run the script and you get something like this:

[image]

[image]

---

UPDATE

and here is an idea how you could even animate it:

```
import bpy

ob = bpy.data.objects['Next']

print("ob is",ob.name)

def object_selected_callback(ob):
    # Do something here
    print("object active ", bpy.context.active_object.name)
    
    if bpy.context.active_object.name == "Next":
        
        cam = bpy.data.objects["Camera"]
        cam.location.x = 21.3
        
    if bpy.context.active_object.name == "Back":
        
#        cam = bpy.data.objects["Camera"]
#        cam.location.x = 0
        
        bpy.context.scene.frame_current = 100
        bpy.ops.screen.animation_play()



def subscribe_to_cube_loc_change(ob):
    
    print("called")
    
    if ob.type != 'MESH':
        return

    subscribe_to = bpy.types.LayerObjects, "active"
    bpy.msgbus.subscribe_rna(
        key = subscribe_to,
        owner = ob,
        args = (ob,),
        notify = object_selected_callback,
        )

subscribe_to_cube_loc_change(ob)

def my_handler(scene):
    
    paus=200
    
    print("Frame Change", scene.frame_current)
    if bpy.context.scene.frame_current ==paus-1:
        
        bpy.ops.screen.animation_cancel()
        bpy.context.scene.frame_current = paus

#remove all handlers
for i in range( len( bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre ) ):
        bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.pop()

#append handler
bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(my_handler)
```

result:

[image]